# How to simulate a "TLS handshake timeout" [ERR_TLS_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT] timeout error?

Tags: node.js

Occasionally my HTTPS server will produce a client error:

```js
require('https').createServer().on('clientError', () => { /* ... */ });
```

That reads:

```
Error [ERR_TLS_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT]: TLS handshake timeout
  at TLSSocket._handleTimeout (_tls_wrap.js:868:22)
  at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:427:28)
  at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:321:20)
  at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:485:12)
  at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:478:8)
  at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
  at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
```

How do I simulate a HTTP request that produces this error?

Comment: Why not just simulate the error itself instead of the request? Like `yourServer.emit('clientError', new Error('[ERR_TLS_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT]: TLS handshake timeout'))`?

Comment: It is one thing to test that individual pieces of code work and another how they interoperate. In this case, I am writing integration tests.

Answer (score 1):

Simply send [`CONNECT`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/CONNECT) request and do not establish connection, i.e.

```js
require('net')
  .connect(serverPort)
  .write(
    [
      'CONNECT 127.0.0.1 HTTP/1.1',
      '\r\n\r\n',
    ].join('\r\n'),
  );
```